# How to converting path into shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, creative-cloud, cc-2017

When I create shape, in the layers panel it is created as a **PATH**. Because of this my shape don't show the points that are used to change the **corner radius**. I want a way to convert the path into a shape.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Live Corners widget

> The Live Corners widget is enabled when you select the **Direct Selection tool** and you have a path selection containing corner points. A Live Corners widget is displayed next to a corner when you select:
>
> - One or more path(s) that have corners.
> - One or more rounded corners

[image]

[*Adobe.com*](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/reshape-with-live-corners.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Photoshop "shape" has well defined meaning. There it's a filled area with vector mask.

In Illlustrator there's no special object type ="shape". Illustrator users call visible objects shapes without especially saying are they paths, symbol instances, bitmap patterns etc...

Live corners are possible with paths. As explained already by others, you can make live corner widgets visible by selecting an object or a corner with the direct selection tool.